# SAS drives as separate logical drives for VMs on Xensever 7.6

Tags: hp, xenserver, sas

I have 6 72GB SAS drives on my HP DL580 but they all show up as one collective Logical Dive.

Is there a way to have seperate drives so I can pass them to the VMs to be used as such ?

Comment: Why do you want to pass the physical drives to your Xen VMs?

Comment: My experience with a server is limited to running a small ubuntu server on my laptop... I got a good deal on a used HP server so I thought about using it to run a few VM's to run multiple servers instead of on my laptop. To me it seemed it would be easier to manage the VM's like multiple computers running Ubuntu server with their data being stored physically in case of emergency. Do correct me if my thought process is wrong or if there is a better way to go about it. I am still reading about this stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Note:** assuming your disks aren't in a RAID volume... if they are, then you'll need to break the RAID volume and re-install.

When you install XenServer, you are asked to create the storage and you are asked which drives to include. You would need to not include any (or only one) and then manually create the storage once the installer is completed.

Now that everything is installed, you still can do it by destroying and re-creating the storage.

You'll have to read the commands documentation to get all the parameters but generally what you are looking for is the `xe` command.

For example, to create a storage repository:

```
xe sr-create type=ext content-type=user \
   device-config:device=/dev/sdX \
   name-label="dataX"
   sm-config:allocation=thin
```

Comment: **Update :** Broke the RAID config using BIOS as the DL580 has a RAID controller (P400) and setup 4 individual RAID disks :

2 X RAID 0
2 X RAID 1+0

Installed XenServer 7.6 (Its a surprise the latest version works on the G5 server) and followed the procedure , and success !!

**Side Note :** I decided to go with KVM as a finality on ubuntu 18.04 instead because that felt more familiar and easier to perform using the documentations on passthrough etc.


Thank you for your reply @ETL.